# POI moving data from a csv to xls

Tags: python, csv, apache-poi, jython, xls

I am relatively new to Python and at the moment I am trying to finish this small piece I am currently working on. 
High-Level: Moving 2 columns of data from a .csv file to an .xls using POI with Jython.
Low-Level: Reading only two columns worth of data from .csv file. Once the data has been read, I organize the data by the data from the second row into different arrays .
e.g.

```
Name    Status              arrayGreen = ['a, Green'], ['aa, Green']
 a      Green               arrayRed = ['b, Red'], ['bb, Red']
 b      Red       TO =>     arrayOrange = ['c, Orange'], ['cc, Orange']
 c      Orange              arrayYellow = ['d, Yellow'], ['dd, Yellow']
 d      Yellow
 aa     Green
 bb     Red
 cc     Orange
 dd     Yellow
```

Once I read that data into arrays I then want to remove the ', ' from the array data since I am now sorting them into groups by array for later use.
So now data looks like this in arrays:

```
arrayGreen = ['a'], ['aa']
arrayRed = ['b'], ['bb']
arrayOrange = ['c'], ['cc']
arrayYellow = ['d'], ['dd']
```

Now I want to start using apache POI to use the data in the arrays and write them to .xls I know how to set up some formatting and reading data from .xls with POI but this is where I am stuck on.

Here is my code so far:

```
file = open('CSVItems.csv', 'r')

for line in file.readlines():
    content = [value for value in line.split()]

    arrayGreen = [x for x in content if 'Green' in x]
    arrayRed = [x for x in content if 'Red' in x]
    arrayOrange = [x for x in content if 'Orange' in x]
    arrayYellow = [x for x in content if 'Yellow' in x]

    if arrayGreen:
        arrayGreen = [x.replace(',Green', '') for x in arrayGreen]
        print arrayGreen
    elif arrayRed:
        arrayRed= [x.replace(',Red', '') for x in arrayRed]
        print arrayRed
    elif arrayOrange:
        arrayOrange= [x.replace(',Orange', '') for x in arrayOrange]
        print arrayOrange
    elif arrayYellow:
        arrayYellow= [x.replace(',Yellow', '') for x in arrayYellow]
        print arrayYellow

   Console:
   ['a']
   ['b']
   ['c']
   ['d']
   ['aa']
   ['bb']
   ['cc']
   ['dd']
```

How do I write each arrayGreen, arrayRed, arrayOrange, arrayYellow as its own column in POI with Jython.

End result.xls to look something like this:

```
Green    Red    Orange     Yellow
  a       b        c          d       
  aa      bb       cc         dd
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try reading any of the many Apache POI tutorials? There shouldn't be anything special with jython, just get the jars in place and then follow the java tutorials

Comment: Hi Gagravarr, Yea I have gone through all of them, I am giving it a go at the moment see where I get. Just wanted to see if anyone had a solution for it already really.